# lifting states up in react, button click to change text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand how to "lift a state up" in React. In the below, there are two scripts, App.js and Child.js. The idea is for the h1 tag to read "starting state" when the page is loaded but change to "new state" when the button clicked. However, presently, the page displays "new state" upon load.

What am I doing wrong here? How should I properly lift the state up from Child to App such that the change occurs when the button is clicked?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state_, setState_] = React.useState("starting state");
  const stateHandler = (data) => {
    setState_(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {<Child propAttribute={state_} onClick={stateHandler} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = (props) => {
  const buttonHandler = (event) => {
    props.onClick("new state");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.propAttribute}</h1>
      <button onClick={buttonHandler}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Your code works as expected.

Comment: what's wrong with current implementation then

Comment: Is it just sandbox that’s loading with “new state”? Perhaps it performs as expected elsewhere?

Comment: I ran the code in sandbox and worked as expected. Not sure how it is not working for your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your child component should be as dumb as possible. It shouldn't have its own state - the state should be given to it in its props by the parent. ["Lifting state up" is documented here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

In this updated example I'm passing in an array of text to the parent component, adding that to the state, and then using a new state `count` to check what the child component should be showing.

```js
function App({ data }) {
  
  // Set the states
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(data);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  
  // Work out whether we need to update the state
  function handleClick(data) {
    if (count < text.length - 1) {
      setCount(prev => ++prev);
    }
  }

  // Render the child with the text, and the handler
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child
        text={text[count]}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

// And all the child component accepts is the text
// and the handler - it has no state - it's all dealt
// with by the parent component
function Child({ text, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const data = ['Starting state', 'Next state'];

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Contrasting w/ the example I provided, I didn't give Child a state of its own per se; I sent the App (parent) state to it as propAttribute. Is this a poor design choice/pattern?

Comment: It really depends what `Child` actually does. If it's a button, make it as dumb as possible - just pass it a handler. If it's a form you may want to manage state within that component, and only when the submit button is clicked push that form state to the parent to deal with. Use-cases vary. At some point you may want to use a different state management tool like React context, or Redux if your app is meant to scale, or maybe Recoil. That's a decision you'll have to make at some point.